# Module 'Alamofire' was created for incompatible target arm64 - apple- ios 10

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Module 'Alamofire' was created for incompatible target arm64 - apple- ios 10.
In apple M1 system I am getting this error at the time of building the  project. Using Carthage

Comment: quick question: Did you run with simulator or a real device ?

Comment: In simulator only

Comment: But @zeytin your solution not worked for me

Comment: I see. It can be still needs be done in Alamofire for M1. For example I can`t use Googlemaps with my M1 for long time and keeping check it out the github page.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure; `carthage update --no-use-binaries`

or

try to open by Rosetta and run again.

**applications > xcode > right click > get info** >
click - Open Using Rosetta

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are two steps that I had to perform, to make the project run on M1.

1. Edit the Podfile and add a post install hook like this:

   ```
   post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
   end
   ```

This allows to run your project on a device.

2. Run your Xcode with `Open using Rosetta` setting. (RBM on Xcode icon -> Get Info -> Open using Rosetta)

This will allow you to run your project on simulators.